# Showing all items in textbox suggestions

Tags: c#, textbox, lucene, controls

I wrote a function that after receiving the text, returns suggestions / similar words to the resulting. Returns a list of strings. I connected this function with textbox TEXT changed.

For example, when i put a **car** into textbox,  my function,will return a list of strings with **cars**, **mars** (mars is simmilar word, sb could made a typo).

I want to make sth like autocompletemoe.suggest, but textbox should show every words from this list, not only with the same letters.

For EXAMPLE:

How should it work?
when i put car into textbox
TEXTBOX should suggest for me: **cars**, **mars**

How it works?
when i put car into textbox
TEXTBOX suggested for me **cars** only

I had

```
my_textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = my_AutoCompleteStringCollection;
my_textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
my_textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

---

Hmm, maybe i will describe it in other way. 
Let's assume that method

```
List<String> GiveSimmilar(string ABC_word)
```

exist and it returns all similar words to 'ABC_word'.
I have a Textbox control named "query_text".
Snippet code from MainForm

```
private AutoCompleteStringCollection suggestions;
private void Main_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
// ...
suggestions = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
query_text.AutoCompleteCustomSource = suggestions;
query_text.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
query_text.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
// ...
}
private void query_text_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
suggestions.Clear();
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query_text)) return;
List<string> suggest = GiveSimmilar(query_text.Text);
foreach (string sug in suggest){
suggestions.Add(sug);
Console.WriteLine(sug);
}

}
```

[[image: 1]]https://postimg.cc/image/4zt4g087d/

Comment: at which point in the text are you starting the search?  it would seem that the like search is happening on the first character and therefore looking for c... rather anything after that letter.  Can you share your AutoComplete code so that we can help  you further

Comment: AutoComplete its a built-in method of TextBox control. And it works so that only shows words from the list that have the same previous letters. I want to show all words from the list and i don't know how can i do it :D

Answer (score 0):

your problem is solved with a regular expresion,
(sorry for my english, im working on it :) )

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{

class GetAuto
{
    public GetAuto()
    {
        string text = "cars";
        foreach (var item in GetAutoComplete(text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        } 
    }

    private List<string> GetAutoComplete(string text)
    {
        var lookForSimilarities = Regex.Match(text,"ars");

        var autoComplete = new List<string>();

        if (lookForSimilarities.Success)
        {
            autoComplete.Add("cars");
            autoComplete.Add("mars");
            autoComplete.Add("wars");
            autoComplete.Add("tarso");
        }


        return autoComplete;
    }
 }
}
```

**What im doing here? let me explain it**

with this piece of code im saying
"hey, search all similiarities of "ars""

```
    var lookForSimilarities = Regex.Match(text,"ars");
```

"And if you found similiarities, add all in to a list"

```
        if (lookForSimilarities.Success)
        {
            autoComplete.Add("cars");
            autoComplete.Add("mars");
            autoComplete.Add("wars");
            autoComplete.Add("tarso");
        }
```

"return the result"

```
          return autoComplete;
```

"make a iteration, and show me the result in console,(but in your case is not a console)"

```
       foreach (var item in GetAutoComplete(text))
       {
              Console.WriteLine(item);
       }
```

Comment: You misunderstood me. I already have a function that returns all similar words to the currently entered in the TextBox. I have a problem with displaying them as suggestions textbox. Although I already have a ready list filled with similar words, is a TextBox shows only the words that have the same letter in advance (not taking into account those of another 1 letter). I do not know how to connect this to the list of suggestions TextBox. Picture here:

Comment: In the previous comment i didnt give you, a picture link, so:[Picture](https://postimg.org/image/4zt4g087d/)

Comment: Are you using regular expresion? because If you are not using it that will never work because you need express a pattern.
 ex:
 I want all words that contain "F" or "A" .
regular expresion is used for that work.
if you need a code snippet just tell me.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Just check out my UPDATED POST.